# use arabic string in a javascript file saved in google cloud storage

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, encoding, google-cloud-storage, arabic

I have a JavaScript file saved to a google cloud storage bucket. it includes Arabic such as

```
["كانون الثاني", "فبراير", "مارس", "أبريل", "أيار", "حزيران","تموز", "آب", "أيلول", "تشرين الأول", "تشرين الثاني", "كانون الاول"];
```

when the file is served, these would look like :

```
["Ã™Æ’Ã˜Â§Ã™â€ Ã™Ë†Ã™â€  Ã˜Â§Ã™â€žÃ˜Â«Ã˜Â§Ã™â€ Ã™Å ","Ã™ÂÃ˜Â¨Ã˜Â±Ã˜Â§Ã™Å Ã˜Â±","Ã™â€¦Ã˜Â§Ã˜Â±Ã˜Â³","Ã˜Â£Ã˜Â¨Ã˜Â±Ã™Å Ã™â€ž","Ã˜Â£Ã™Å Ã˜Â§Ã˜Â±","Ã˜Â­Ã˜Â²Ã™Å Ã˜Â±Ã˜Â§Ã™â€ ","Ã˜ÂªÃ™â€¦Ã™Ë†Ã˜Â²","Ã˜Â¢Ã˜Â¨","Ã˜Â£Ã™Å Ã™â€žÃ™Ë†Ã™â€ž","Ã˜ÂªÃ˜Â´Ã˜Â±Ã™Å Ã™â€  Ã˜Â§Ã™â€žÃ˜Â£Ã™Ë†Ã™â€ž","Ã˜ÂªÃ˜Â´Ã˜Â±Ã™Å Ã™â€  Ã˜Â§Ã™â€žÃ˜Â«Ã˜Â§Ã™â€ Ã™Å ","Ã™Æ’Ã˜Â§Ã™â€ Ã™Ë†Ã™â€  Ã˜Â§Ã™â€žÃ˜Â§Ã™Ë†Ã™â€ž"]
```

although the script is being called with charset="utf-8". but even opening the file through the public link (in chrome). shows the scrambled text. where as if I open the file locally using chrome as well, I can see the Arabic literals.
I need to have these Arabic literals served and displayed as they are expected

Comment: The text does not display correctly on an html page when opened in the browser, correct?  Does the page have the correct utf-8 encoding?  See: [meta charset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta#examples)

Comment: yes it does (have the meta charset). it seems like it is getting transformed to the scrambled text upon saving in the bucket (my assumption)

Comment: You face a **double [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake)** case (*example in Python for its universal intelligibility*): ```print('كانون الثاني'.encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'cp1252').encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'cp1252'))``` returns ```Ã™Æ’Ã˜Â§Ã™â€ Ã™Ë†Ã™â€  Ã˜Â§Ã™â€žÃ˜Â«Ã˜Â§Ã™â€ Ã™Å``` …

Answer (score 1):

Posting as a community wiki based on the comment of **@JosefZ**.

You face a **double** [mojibake](https://mojibake) case (*example in Python for its universal intelligibility*): `print('كانون الثاني'.encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'cp1252').encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'cp1252'))` returns `Ã™Æ’Ã˜Â§Ã™â€ Ã™Ë†Ã™â€  Ã˜Â§Ã™â€žÃ˜Â«Ã˜Â§Ã™â€ Ã™Å`…

To add:
Make sure that every pass the content goes through is UTF-8 clean or preserves the original content byte-for-byte exactly. That includes setting Content-type headers appropriately (Likely: text/html; charset=utf-8). This precise issue is why it is recommended to use UTF-8 for all the things.